# YUI Compressor: is the obfuscation safe?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, yui-compressor

[YUI Compressor](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/doc/README) has an option to obfuscate local symbols (it's on by default, and you can turn it off with `--nomunge`. My question is: how safe is this? What are the situations (if any) where it can break code?

Comment: I have not heard of any case that YUI Compressor breaks code by renaming local variables.  However, you might want to Google it a bit to see if there are any edge cases.  You should also look at Uglify and the Closure Compiler -- both of the yield better compression ratios than YUI.

Answer (score 1):

From your link

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The YUI Compressor is a JavaScript compressor which, in addition
>   to removing
>       comments and white-spaces, obfuscates local variables using the
>   smallest
>       possible variable name. **This obfuscation is safe**, even when using
>   constructs
>       such as 'eval' or 'with' (although the compression is not optimal
>   is those
>       cases) Compared to jsmin, the average savings is around 20%.

Comment: But is that really true? With JavaScript being such a dynamic language, it seems like changing a variable name could have unexpected consequences.

Comment: Either you believe what they (the creators say) or you believe what anyone here says. It's the same thing. But note that Yahoo isn't going to pay dummies to write their code.

Comment: Fair enough, but if someone here can provide an example of where it breaks code, then I don't need to believe anyone.

Comment: Saying "This obfuscation is safe" is a pretty bold statement.. All I can say is that if it's good enough for Yahoo to use, then...
You can always break javascript if that is your intention though.